# which is the property way of update position of each frame's animation with libgdx?

Tags: animation, libgdx

I just need to know which is the best way to change frame's position with `Animation` class and `libgdx`:

I make an `Animation` object with many `TextureRegions` and I found this solution for update the frame's position in the render method:

```
batch.begin();
if (currentFrame.equals(tex1))
    batch.draw(currentFrame, w, h,120,160); 
else if (currentFrame.equals(tex2))
    batch.draw(currentFrame, w+5, h+10,120,160);
    batch.end();
```

This draw each frame of animation in different position, in sequence;
is this a good solution or exist something better?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After you have initialized your animation object, you just get the current frame using the getKeyFrame method and draw it with the batch:

```
TextureRegion currentFrame = animation.getKeyFrame(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime(), true);
batch.draw(currentFrame, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Hi : thanks for reply ; your solution just draw the current frame at the location 0,0   , but doesnt permit to chooce exactly  the x-y position because the render's method is called 60 times for second and the effect isnt good ; try to imagine to draw the ryu's shoryuken of street fighter 2 , where each frame must be in precise position

Comment: If you want to change its position just draw it using two variables: batch.draw(currentFrame, x, y); If I understand correctly you have your frames on the same position and you want to move them on the animation. You can make a 2d array and move the currentframe by the value in the current's frame index on the the array. For example:  I use 0 for x and 1 for y, positionChangeX = positionChanges[0][currentFrame.getFrameIndex(1/15f)]; positionChangeY = positionChanges[1][currentFrame.getFrameIndex(1/15f)] and then draw(currentFrame, w + positionChangeX, h + positionChangeY);

Comment: hi : thanks for reply : do you think that is it a good practise while we use box 2d or is just better calculate the new location is the end of the animation ?

Comment: If their isn't any relationship between the position changes then there isn't something better i cant think of. As you use box2d, move the bodies first and then get the position of the bodies and position the frames accordingly.